# Disable Automatic unittesting in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

PyCharm automatically detects when files begin with `test_`, and tries to run them as Unittests.  Which is very considerate, but something seems to be broken, and on any test I run, I get

```
/Users/peter/projects/plato/venv/bin/python2.7 "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py" /Users/peter/projects/plato/utils/tools/test_sampling.py::::test_samplers_not_broken true
Testing started at 10:58 AM ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 140, in <module>
    all.addTest(testLoader.makeTest(getattr(module, a[2])))
AttributeError: 'TestLoader' object has no attribute 'makeTest'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

All I want to do is run them as normal python files, but PyCharm won't let me.  Eclipse gives the option to run normally or run as unittest.  This is annoying!  How can I do this?

Comment: Still whenever I make and run a new file called test_<something> it automatically assumes it should run it with UnitTest, and it always causes the same error, until I go to edit configurations and remove it.  Is there no way just to permanently disable this annoying UnitTest thing?

Comment: Problem remains unsolved.  The temporary fix is to to click on the drop-down list on the top right of PyCharm, go "Edit Configurations", remove the file you're trying to run from "Python Unittest" ("-" sign), then right-click on the file and click "run" (note - don't use the keyboard shortcut or it will run as UnitTest again).  From then on, PyCharm will remember that that particular file should not be run as a UnitTest, but you will still have to repeat for any future `test_...` file you create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me setting `Settings -> Tools -> Python Integrated tools -> Testing` to `Unittests` worked.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Press [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rle5T.png) (small gray arroy pointing down near settings button on tools panel above editor)
Choose 'Edit Configuration'

There you can choose what tests pycharm should run and when. Probably there set `All in folder` button, choose another option like `script`

Also you should check bottom part of your file, after `if __name__ == '__main__'`

maybe you have code there that automatically launches test when you run this file

Comment: Hmm.  Having trouble replicating the problem now, but it looks like you were right.  It's not a small-gray arrow any more but a little tab on the top-right that would say "UnitTest blahblahblach.py", got to "Edit Configurations...", select the UnitTest in question, click "-" on the top-left.   Then "Apply".

Comment: @Peter, can you please accept it as correct answer?

Comment: While "Edit Configurations" is a helpful lead, the answer doesn't really work.  In `Edit Configurations>Defaults>Python tests>Unittests` it is already set to "script" and it still runs files starting with `test_` as unittests.  The question asks how one can globally disable automatic testing.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had configuration set to > Test: Class

Once changed to Script it works without splashing any errors.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

My temporary solution is to add a block at the bottom of the page.

`if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass`

To the left of the block in the fields there will be a button for running the script without testing.

[image]
[image]

Additionally you can track this problem [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19687#u=1486029486672).

**Note:**
If **files** or **functions** in the file begin with **test_**, then PyCharm tries to run the scripts as the default **Unittests**.

**UPD 31/01/2018:**
I tried to capture an example of how he works for me

[image]

Also, you can always look at options without a block with if (`Shift+Alt+F10`)

[image]

Comment: Please do not down rating the post silently. Write what exactly you do not agree with. Thanks!

Comment: Your file is not named test_*.py.  When I try your approach on a file beginning in test_ it just runs unittests

Comment: @Peter, I supplemented my answer. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Hmmm what version of pycharm do you have?  I don't have the little arrows next to Run 'test_XXX'.  It's just a button, which launches unit tests

Comment: @Peter, version PyCharm 2017.1;
Build #PY-171.3780.115, built on March 24, 2017;
JRE: 1.8.0_131-b11 x86;
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM by Oracle Corporation;
Windows 8.1 6.3;
Python on screenshots 2.7.13
-
Maybe you will give me your file (preferably with a structure) for the test?

Comment: When I run a file identical to yours it runs in test mode.  However, I've discovered it appears to depend on the project you're in.  Guessing pycharm detects some test config file somewhere in the project, but haven't figured out which yet (eliminated `conftest.py` and `pytest.ini`)

Comment: @Peter, ok. And you tried to launch through the context menu (Shift+Alt+F10)  ?
How about sharing with me your project, if possible, to try to identify the problem together?

Comment: Hi.  Appreciate it but project is for a company and confidential.  I'll post here again if I figure out the solution.

Comment: And yes, tried through the "Run Context Configuration" option (Shift-Alt-F10)